# Accessing SAS(9.04) from Anaconda

Tags: python, sas, anaconda, saspy

We are doing a POC to see how to access SAS data sets from Anaconda 
All documentation i find says only SASpy works with SAS 9.4 or higher

Our SAS version is 9.04.01M3P062415

Can this be done? If yes any documentation in this regard will be highly appreciated

Many thanks in Advance!

Comment: Documentation is on GitHub, you need Python is the only requirement. Since Jupyterlab also works, I assume once you have saspy/python installed and working correctly it likely won't matter what you use to run Python itself. https://github.com/sassoftware/saspy

Comment: Also, you pay for SAS support - feel free to ask them. That's the benefit of having a support license.

Comment: SASpy should work with your version of SAS.  You are running 9.4TS1M3.  That is a couple of years old, but not that old.  Current release is 9.4TS1M6.  But it might be overkill if all you need to do is read SAS datasets.

Comment: Hi Tom, The aim is to run SAS programs from jupyter not only read datasets. Is there a way please?

Comment: But, in case you just want to run SAS programs, can you not submit the job to the GRID via shell?

Answer (score 0):

SAS datasets are ODBC compliant. SasPy is for running SAS code. If the goal is to read SAS datasets, only, use ODBC or OleDb. I do not have Python code but SAS has a lot of documentation on doing this using C#. Install the free SAS ODBC drivers and read the sas7bdat. The drivers are on the SAS website.

Writing it is different but reading should be fine. You will lose some aspects of the dataset but data will come through.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. The aim is to run SAS programs from jupyter not only read datasets. Is there a way please?

Comment: Do you have SAS/intrNet or Integration Technologies licensed? They can be used to submit SAS commands. SASPy is your best bet but it is not the only one. On a 9.0 system, you may have IntrNet (older product but works fantastic for something like this). Integration Technologies is the easiest.

Comment: Oh ok will explore this. Thanks Alan

Comment: Henry, determine what you have, let us know, and then I can share some code (in C#, not Python) and it should get you over the hump.